# Regex for number up to 16 digits with optional decimal any place within number

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find the correct regex pattern to match any number up to 16 digits max, with an optional decimal point anywhere in the number.  Here are some examples.

Valid:

- 9999999999999999
- 0.000000000000001
- 3.24
- 1.2
- 0.00003

Invalid:

- 12345678910111213
- 59.492.5

Comment: Is `.0` a valid case here or `0000000000000000` ?

Comment: Those are invalid. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assumed that you don't want to allow `.number` (ie, the below regex won't match the numbers like  `.67`, `.08`),

```
^(?:(?=.{3,17}$)\d+\.\d+|\d{1,16})$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xY3sK0/2)

Answer (score 2):

based on the comment above that `.0` `0000000000` and `0000003` are not valid, use this pattern

```
^(?!0\d|\.|.*?\..*?\.)(?=(?:\.?\d){1,16}$)(.*)$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/99)